# Query company name, return headquarters physical address using python?

Tags: python, location

Is it possible to search for a company through google and have it return the company headquarters address? Let's say I want to search for Google HQ, I would enter google headquarters and `1600 Amphitheatre Parkway` would return. Does anyone know any library or api that would be able to help me with this or even a huge list of companies with addresses?

Comment: this sounds like something a webscraper could do, possibly check out scrapy https://scrapy.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably an API that has this information, but a Google search for "get company headquarters physical address" turned up a website [Corporate Office Headquarters.com](http://www.corporate-office-headquarters.com) that could be used as a query point and parsed with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

company = 'google'

url = 'http://www.corporate-office-headquarters.com/search-static?term={c}&page=1&rows=200'.format(c=company)

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

endpoint = soup.find('a', href=True, attrs={'class': "match-result-anchor"})['href']

url = 'http://www.corporate-office-headquarters.com/{ep}'.format(ep=endpoint)

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

HQ_address = soup.find_all('dd')[2]   # locate the Address Tag

print(HQ_address.text)
```

Should display:

```
1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
```

Of course there are many other possible solutions.